# What determines how much gas is required when transferring an ECR-721 non-fungible token?

Tags: gas, gas-estimate, nft

When transferring an ECR-721 token, what determines how much gas is required?  Is it written into the contract of the ECR-721 token?  Does it depend upon how it was transferred (e.g. cryptokitties.com vs OpenSea.io)?

How can the amount of gas be appropriately estimated for this type of token transfer?

Comment: Is the gas/fees only determined by the ECR-721 SmartContract?  Can nothing else modify the gas/fees?

Comment: Gas is computed from the contract executed instructions, nobody else from the outside can change the gas.